# Using CocoaPods and Obj-C Bridging Headers

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, cocoapods

When you include 3rd party Obj-C libraries and use the Obj-C Bridging Header, you are able to directly use the integrated libraries without the `import` statement.

```
//Bridging header
#import <Parse/Parse.h>
#import <Bolts/Bolts.h>

//Now, within the project, I can make calls to the Parse library without imports.
```

However, if I include 3rd party Obj-C libraries using CocoaPods, this doesn't seem to be the case. I needed the import statement for each file to use the library.

Is there a way to rectify this?

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this using Bridging Header similarly as you had it without Pods, follow the  steps.

1. Keep your bridging header at the project home directory.

   ie., if your project name is SampleProject. Usually you keep your Bridging header at the position SampleProject->SampleProject->Bridging-Header.h

   But now, keep it at SampleProject->Bridging-Header.h
2. Get your pods library header file's path and import it inside your Bridging-Header.h file as usually.

(Refer this [link](https://github.com/SureshKumarD/SwiftParseLogin/blob/master/Bridging-Header.h) for details.)

Remaining things will work like a charm.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the tip. In addition to the steps you've listed, I also changed the path in the `build settings` to reflect the changes. However, I wasn't able to get the desired result. Without the `import` statement, the compiler could not recognize the 3rd-party library.

Comment: Updated the refer link url.